# NodeJS Sequelize make main table descending example

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I got stuck how to make descending main table in NodeJS. I've developed like that

```
models.Users.findAll({
    where: {id: usersArray},
    include: [
        {model: models.Users_Answers}
    ],
    order: [
        [models.Users_Answers, 'id', 'ASC']
    ]
}).then(function(answers) {
    /* Do something */ 
});
```

But error encountered when I changed as below, error encountered.

```
models.Users.findAll({
    where: {id: usersArray},
    include: [
        {model: models.Users_Answers}
    ],
    order: [
        [models.Users, 'id', 'DESC']
        [models.Users_Answers, 'id', 'ASC']
    ]
}).then(function(answers) {
    /* Do something */ 
});
```

> Unhandled rejection Error: 'Users' in order / group clause is not
>   valid association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it like this,

```
models.Users.findAll({
    where: {id: usersArray},
    include: [
        {model: models.Users_Answers}
    ],
    order: [
        [db.Sequelize.col('id'), 'DESC'],
        [models.Users_Answers, 'id', 'ASC']
    ]
}).then(function(answers) {
    /* Do something */ 
});
```